In what situations does `ranges::for_each` work but `for (auto&& elt : rg)` fail?
Given the following C++23 code (Godbolt):
template<class R, class T>
concept container_compatible_range =
  std::ranges::input_range<R> && std::convertible_to<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>, T>;

template<class K, class V>
struct Map {
  using value_type = std::pair<K, V>;

  template<class R>
    requires container_compatible_range<R, value_type>
  void insert_range_bad(R&& rg) {
    for (value_type e : rg) {
      // ~~~~
    }
  }

  template<class R>
    requires container_compatible_range<R, value_type>
  void insert_range_good(R&& rg) {
    std::ranges::for_each(rg, [&](value_type e) {
      // ~~~~
    });
  }
};

int main() {
  Map<int, int> m;
  std::tuple<int, int> a[2] = {};  // for example
  m.insert_range_bad(a);
  m.insert_range_good(a);
}

I've been told that there are "contrived corner cases" where insert_range_good will successfully compile, but insert_range_bad will fail (in a SFINAE-unfriendly, hard-error kind of way) and/or Do The Wrong Thing.
What are these corner cases?

Was use of a C-array for the example chosen arbitrarily? Because it seems to me that C-arrays are the singular category of range that would be immune to any differences here...

"it seems to me that C-arrays are the singular category of range that would be immune to any differences" — Can you cite another category of range that would have differences? I mean, that's the question being asked. :) I used a core-language array here simply because it's the simplest: "Prefer core-language features over library facilities".

I've now turned this into a blog post over at https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2024/12/09/foreach-versus-for/ . Thanks, @康桓瑋, for the explanation!

Range-based for loops extract the range's iterator and sentinel in a consistent way, which means both must be obtained through member function or free functions.
This is not case for ranges::for_each, as both can be retrieved in different ways via ranges::begin and ranges::end respectively:
struct EvilRange {
  std::tuple<int, int>* begin() const;
};

std::tuple<int, int>* end(EvilRange&);

int main() {
  Map<int, int> m;
  EvilRange evil;
  m.insert_range_bad(evil);  // failed
  m.insert_range_good(evil); // ok
}

Another contrived case is to delete the begin/end members but enable free begin/end functions; the class still satisfies the range concept as ranges::begin/ranges::end checks the validity of the expression, whereas range-based for loops does not:
struct EvilRange2 {
  void begin() = delete;
  void end() = delete;
};

std::tuple<int, int>* begin(EvilRange2&);
std::tuple<int, int>* end(EvilRange2&);

int main() {
  Map<int, int> m;
  EvilRange2 evil;
  m.insert_range_bad(evil);  // failed
  m.insert_range_good(evil); // ok
}


Thanks! And yikes: I feel like ranges::begin and ranges::end are being uncharacteristically permissive here. It would have been simple to require that the begin and end of a range both be provided in the same way (~correlates with "by the same programmer"); a thing whose begin and end come from different places probably isn't really a range, and I would have expected ranges::range to catch that. But since it currently doesn't, awesome, this is the difference I was looking for!

Range types that model range are not guaranteed to be traversable via range-based for loops feel not quite right though.
